# Write Array to Cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The code finds the first and last occurrence of a sting in a range then builds a array. My problem is I'm not sure how to write the array to a cell in a comma delimited format to the worksheet. The .Find searches from the beginning of the range forward and the second .Find searches from the end of the range back. Both stop on the first occurrence of the search variable.

Questions:
1. how to improve the code for speed as the this will be searching ranges in the 100,000+ row range
2. how to write the created array into a comma delimited string in a worksheet.

```
Public Function FindVehicleOptions()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim CellAddress As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Search As String
Dim NumRows As Long
Dim NumCols As Long
Dim Key As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook: Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("AFS Configuration Ver 2.xlsm")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Configuration")
Dim Destination As Range
Dim sDelimString As String
Dim lCounter As Long

FindString = Sheets("AFS Report").Range("A3")

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With ws1.Range("B:B")
        Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindString, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng1, True
                Debug.Print Rng1.Address
            Else
                Debug.Print "Nothing found"
            End If
    End With
End If

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With ws1.Range("B:B")
        Set Rng2 = .Find(What:=FindString, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng2, True
                Debug.Print Rng2.Address
                    CellAddress = Rng2.Address
                    Set Cell = Range(CellAddress)
            Else
                Debug.Print "Nothing found"
            End If
    End With
End If

vArr = ws1.Range(Rng1.Address & ":" & Rng2.Offset(0, 5).Address).Value

Debug.Print "New value of " & Rng1.Address & Rng2.Offset(0, 5).Address

NumRows = UBound(vArr, 1) - LBound(vArr, 1) + 1
NumCols = UBound(vArr, 2) - LBound(vArr, 2) + 1
Set Destination = Range("B3")
Destination.Resize(UBound(vArr, 2), UBound(vArr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(vArr)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typical example of placing a two dimensional array into a single cell in **csv** form:

```
Sub dural()
Dim vArray(1 To 3, 1 To 5) As Long, K As Long
Dim rDestination As Range, sTringg As String
Set rDestination = Range("B9")

K = 1
For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 5
        vArray(i, j) = K
        K = K + 1
    Next j
Next i

sTringg = ""
For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)
        sTringg = sTringg & "," & vArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
sTringg = Mid(sTringg, 2, Len(sTringg) - 1)

rDestination = sTringg

End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering part of what i need to do is also extract every fifth element from the array. I've been using 
vArr = Application.Index(vArr, 0, 5)

wondering if there is a better method. This is new territory for me.

Comment: How can i sort the array before placing it into the csv format? I'm attempting to follow the code from cpearson.com "QSortInPlace" and I'm getting an error that the array is multi-dimensional. I thought that if it was (1 to 28, 1 to 1) it was a single dimension.

Comment: @User406160  Open a new post.